# Integrate: $\int \frac{\sin(x)}{9+16\sin(2x)}\,\text{d}x$.

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Integrate: $$\int \frac{\sin(x)}{9+16\sin(2x)}\,\text{d}x.$$

I tried the substitution method ($\sin(x) = t$) and ended up getting $\int \frac{t}{9+32t-32t^3}\,\text{d}t$. Don't know how to proceed further.

Also tried adding and substracting $\cos(x)$ in the numerator which led me to get $$\sin(2x) = t^2-1$$ by taking $\sin(x)+\cos(x) = t$.

Can't figure out any other method now. Any suggestions or tips?

Comment: Try the angent half-angle substitution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution.

Comment: And in the substitution $\sin x = t$ you've fogotten the $dx$.

Comment: Is this integral given this way, or as a defined integral? Because if you need to integrate from 0 to $2 \pi$ that is an easier task.

Comment: @N.S. I was given in this way but I would love to see the method on how to solve this integral from 0 to 2pi.

Comment: @Gauz If you use $z(t) =cos(t)+i \sin(t)$ you can express this integral as the integral of a rational function over the circle of radius one in the complex plane. Then the residue Theorem calculates this immediately. The solution relies on complex analysis though...

Comment: @Gauz, If it was from 0 to 2$\pi$, you could have put x=2$\pi$-x, and added both integrals, then took sinx-cosx=t, it would have killed the problem.

Comment: @Nikunj if I replace x by 2pi-x, how would that break the integral into 2 parts? Sorry I think I am missing something that you are trying to explain. Can you elaborate more on that please?

Comment: @Gauz oops, my bad, I was thinking about the upper limit being as $\pi/2$, and not 2$\pi$.

Comment: @Nikunj even if the upper limit was pi/2, how would you solve it? Just need some tips so as to proceed.

Comment: @Gauz ok, In the given integral, put x=π/2-x, you can do this as, $\int_a^b f(x)dx=\int_a^b f(a+b−x)dx$ next add the two to get sinx+cosx in the numerator and then put sinx-cosx=t, you can represent sin2x easily in terms of t

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To attack this integral, we will need to make use of the following facts:

$$(\sin{x} + \cos{x})^2 = 1+\sin{2x}$$

$$(\sin{x} - \cos{x})^2 = 1-\sin{2x}$$

$$\text{d}(\sin{x}+\cos{x}) = (\cos{x}-\sin{x})\text{d}x$$

$$\text{d}(\sin{x}-\cos{x}) = (\cos{x}+\sin{x})\text{d}x$$

Now, consider the denominator.

It can be rewritten in two different ways as hinted by the above information.

$$9+16\sin{2x} = 25 - 16(1-\sin{2x}) = 16(1+\sin{2x})-7$$

$$9+16\sin{2x} = 25 - 16(\sin{x}-\cos{x})^2 = 16(\sin{x}+\cos{x})^2-7$$

Also note that

$$\text{d}(\sin{x}-\cos{x})-\text{d}(\sin{x}+\cos{x}) = 2\sin{x}\text{d}x$$

By making the substitutions

$$u = \sin{x}+\cos{x}, v = \sin{x}-\cos{x}$$

The integral is transformed into two separate integrals which can be evaluated independently.

$$2I = \int \frac{\text{d}v - \text{d}u}{9+16\sin{2x}} = \int \frac{\text{d}v}{25-16v^2} + \int \frac{\text{d}u}{7-16u^2}$$

The remainder of this evaluation is left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$\int\frac{\sin(x)}{9+16\sin(2x)}\space\text{d}x=$$

---

Use the double angle formula $\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$:

---

$$\int\frac{\sin(x)}{32\sin(x)\cos(x)+9}\space\text{d}x=$$

---

Subsitute $u=\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$ and $\text{d}u=\frac{\sec^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{2}\space\text{d}x$.

Then transform the integrand using the substitutions:

$\sin(x)=\frac{2u}{u^2+1},\cos(x)=\frac{1-u^2}{u^2+1}$ and $\text{d}x=\frac{2}{u^2+1}\space\text{d}u$:

---

$$\int\frac{4u}{\left(u^2+1\right)^2\left(\frac{64u(1-u^2)}{(u^2+1)^2}+9\right)}\space\text{d}u=$$
$$\int\frac{4u}{9 u^4-64 u^3+18 u^2+64 u+9}\space\text{d}u$$